# Automated forwarding of emails on Outlook (where forwarded email is exactly same as original)

Tags: email, automation, microsoft-outlook-2013

How can I forward an email based on the sender and subject such that it looks exactly the same as the initial email (i.e. it wont include FW: in the subject, or the sender info, etc) in Outlook 2013?

Comment: Any updates on your issue?

Comment: @JoyZhang Thanks for the help. But I dont have an exchange account, so the first suggestion won't work for me. With regard to the second one, I wanted a process which would automatically forward a particular email without the "FW" but also without me intervening to confirm the same. If I change the macro, then all forwarded emails will show up without "FW" but I just want this specific email to have that

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of your email account? Is it a exchange account?

If this a exchange account, you could configure a transport rule to add another account in "To or CC" filed. Screenshot for your reference:
[image]

If you use another type email account, there seems no auto-method through inbox rule to delete "FW" word , but I have found a blog on [how to let Outlook auto remove FW with VBA](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/auto-remove-prefix-re-fw-subject-replying-forwarding-emails/), hope it is helpful to you.